# Having difficulties with reading XML properly

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading XML files that are on websites. The name of the channel and it's "id" is stored in a .txt file and is used when reading the XML page. This is the code that works for me no problem with own3d.tv:

```
public void checkOnline()
{
    try
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=" + OTVid);
        bool done = false;
        while (reader.Read() && !done)
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    if (OTVstreamOnline != bool.Parse(reader.Value) && !OTVoverridden)
                    {
                        OTVstreamOnline = bool.Parse(reader.Value);
                        if (OTVstreamOnline)
                        {
                            OTVonlineStreams++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            OTVonlineStreams--;
                        }
                        OTVAnnounce();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    done = true;
                    Console.WriteLine(OTVnick + " online = " + OTVstreamOnline);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (XmlException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File not found.");
    }
}
```

When reading it's XML, it's something like this:

```
<own3dReply>
 <liveEvent>
  <isLive>true</isLive>
  <liveViewers>96</liveViewers>
  <liveDuration>115046</liveDuration>
 </liveEvent>
</own3dReply>
```

Which works perfectly. The whole purpose of this is to check if isLive is true then OTVonlineStreams++; otherwise if false OTVonlineStreams--;

However, I need to use http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.xml?channel= and I'm struggling to do it with the method I used above. The xml file when online is like this:

```
<streams>
 <stream>
  <broadcast_part>1</broadcast_part>
  <featured>True</featured>
  <channel_subscription>False</channel_subscription>
  <audio_codec>mp3</audio_codec>
  <embed_count>253</embed_count>
  <id href="/stream/show/2281837264.xml">2281837264</id>
  <category>gaming</category>
  <title>EG's DeMoN - Streaming DotA 2</title>
  <video_height>720</video_height>
  <site_count>116</site_count>
  <embed_enabled>True</embed_enabled>
  <up_time>Wed Dec 21 03:43:00 2011</up_time>
  <meta_game>Dota 2</meta_game>
  <format>live</format>
  <stream_type>live</stream_type>
  <channel_count>648</channel_count>
  <abuse_reported>False</abuse_reported>
  <video_width>1280</video_width>
  <geo>MY</geo>
  <name href="/stream/show/live_user_dotademon.xml">live_user_dotademon</name>
  <language>en</language>
  <stream_count>369</stream_count>
  <video_bitrate>1720.34375</video_bitrate>
 </stream
</streams>
```

When it's offline, the XML is just:

```
<results/>
```

How would I use the justin.tv one like the one I did with the own3d.tv one? All the justin.tv one really needs to do is check if there is XML other than `<results/>`, if there is, do OTVonlineStreams++ etc. I have no idea where to begin with it and I've tried many other ways of reading the file, which I can, but then I struggle to update all my stuff like OTVonlineStreams++ etc.

I know this isn't the place to ask this type of question specifically and for someone to do it for me, but I really can't figure this out. I'm learning C# so go easy on me please :] So the major question is, how do I read the justin.tv one precisely like I did with own3d.tv?

Here's a link to pastebin containing the entire file's contents for what I'm talking about: http://pastebin.com/hZex2UBg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your own3d.tv query, this is a nice place where you can use a LINQ one-liner instead of manually parsing the XML;

```
int count = (from e in doc.Descendants("isLive") where (bool)e select e).Count();
```

For your second request, try this;

```
int count = doc.Descendants("stream").Count();
```

Take a look here for documentation on XDocument (which is what `doc` is in the example above); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I tried the following to test it: http://pastebin.com/EeAM0xEP

How would I use this with my example above? With the OTVonlineStrams++; etc, that's where I get stuck, how do I use that with the above like you said.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: Hi @user1104783: Did the code in your pastebin link return what you expected?

Comment: Well it returned 1 if the stream was online and 0 if it wasn't, according to the code in the pastebin. It's what I need, but how do I then use it with my example in this question? The first one. Something like this? This doesn't work but it's what I mean: http://pastebin.com/2Cpj7aSw

Comment: The code in the first pastebin would return 1 if it found isLive or stream for example, if it didn't, it would return 0. I want to use that method with my above mentioned pastebin example. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @user1104783: Maybe use this instead; http://pastebin.com/7jEJYi0W. Note, are you sure you really want to decrement OTVonlineStreams when a stream is offline? That means if one stream is online and another is offline, that your total will be 0 (1 + -1). Should you not just be only incrementing, like in my pastebin link? Apologies if I'm being presumptuous!

Comment: that works well in the console, but when it comes to http://pastebin.com/tPSmjY0L  it always posts "Broadcast ended" instead of Now broadcasting, even thought it's broadcasting. Works fine in the console but the IRC output is always "broadcast ended". I have no idea why. Thanks for all the help. I feel like as if I'm dragging you on and on. Don't feel obliged to solve it all for me though. :P I can upload the entire project if you want. I've just been struggling with this for days now. :S

Comment: Here is the whole project if you have any time to look at it. Any help would be appreciated. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38791214/dev/testbed.rar

Comment: @user1104783: This is just a general point, but it looks like you're using a lot of global variables and relying on side-effects inside your methods. This is always going to be error prone. You should try and encapsulate your methods a bit more and pass info around as params and returns. Anyway.. when you debug through checkOnline(), what's the value of OTVstreamOnline?

Comment: @user1104783: I took a look at your code, the problem seems to be that you are declaring OTVstreamOnline locally inside checkOnline, but in your announce method are referring to the class level property which is *also* called OTVstreamOnline. Remove the "bool" from the start so you just have this statement; "OTVstreamOnline = (bool) doc.Descendants("isLive").FirstOrDefault();". Also, I misspoke when advising to remove the decrement counter earlier. That was incorrect, but your handling of online streams needs a bit more work to account for various edge cases (like all streams being offline).

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It's working properly now. Really appreciate it. Cheers mate

Comment: @user1104783: Glad to help :) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got it right, but I think what could help you is an XSLT Transformation.

That means, you are using a transformation for each of your TV services, which is transforming the provider specific XML into a standardized XML format that can be used by your code.

This way you can easily add other providers later on and your code stays the same, regardless which provider you are using. Nice benefit is you are skipping all the data you don't need and you can do simple calculations/condition checks in the transformation.
This way you could check if the node `<results/>` exists and then output `<isLive>true</isLive>` or `<isLive>false</isLive>`.

Have a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

And an example for transforming XML to XML:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT#Example_1_.28transforming_XML_to_XML.29

Answer (score 0):

as said before, you should use the Linq oner-liner - as C.McAtakney said.

I just completed his sample with that to perform to your example...

my "sample.xml" taking your sample xml ... hope that will help u :)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace xmlRead
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("sample.xml");
            XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            //checking if theire a results element ?
            int count = myDoc.Descendants("results").Count();

            if (count == 0)
            {
                //do what your programs does to do
                //for example reading embed_enabled and put in variable declared before :)

                XElement embededEnabled = (from xml2 in myDoc.Descendants("embed_enabled") select xml2).FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine("item to: {0}", embededEnabled);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```